# EXTJs - Pasting data in HTML editor inserts a blank space in Editor

Tags: extjs

Created an HTML Editor  in Extjs

```
   {
                    xtype: 'htmleditor',
                    fieldLabel: 'Description',
                    name: 'description',
                    width: 600,
                    height: 200,

                    grow: true
                },
```

As soon as i Copy text from any HTML website/webpage, it inserts an empty line in the code as (Saw it from Chrome -> Insert Element) :

```
<pre class="bz_comment_text" id="comment_text_0" style="font-size: medium; white-space: pre-wrap; width: 50em;">Pasted this text from from HTML PAGe</pre>
```

This breaks the code and headings from panel are removed as soon as we hit  "Save as Draft" Button Created.
HELP!

Comment: can you provide a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) for this issue and I will help you solve it

Comment: @Scriptable Added Code https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ib3

Comment: @Scriptable Use Ext JS 4.2.1.883 Classic
As soon as i Copy and paste some text into the HTML editor and click on Source Editor It shows a "<pre class="bz_comment_text" id="comment_text_0" style="font-size: medium; white-space: pre-wrap; width: 50em;">" attached, this kills my database